# Bash Script; process macOS disk number based on drive size... GREP

Tags: linux, macos, bash, grep, disk-utility

I'm looking to script a few CoreStorage commands on drives automatically. The problem is one of the drives is external, which means it can appear mounted on the system as anything from disk2 to disk4 and I can't reliably guess.

The drive however will always either be 5TB or 8TB as listed by diskutil. So would a GREP wizard be able to come up with a way to search diskutil list for 5TB or 8TB drives and if found use that identifier in the following command?

I have some pieces of the puzzle, but not quite enough to know how to search for 5TB or 8TB and then enter the resulting disk number into the variable.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal): 
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE         IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                         1.0 TB       disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB     disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            900.4 GB     disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB     disk0s3
   4:                  Apple_HFS Golden                  61.0 GB      disk0s4
   5:         Microsoft Reserved                         16.8 MB      disk0s5
   6:       Microsoft Basic Data                         38.0 GB      disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE         IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Mac HD                 +900.0 GB     disk1
                             Logical Volume on disk0s2
                             3CE3A410-049C-42DC-AB48-2191A122F04F
                             Unencrypted

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.5 TB       disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB     disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Time Machine Backups    1.5 TB       disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   +1.5 TB       disk3
```

The diskutil output looks like the above. I don't have any of the drives i'd want to target but lets say I want the disk identifier for the 1.0 TB drive which is disk0 in a

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1220227/edit) to include some of the output of `diskutil` with and without the disk you want to identify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your output looks like that in [this example](https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO109622.html) you could use `awk` to get the `Disk:` value as follows:

```
diskutil list | awk '/(1.0|5.0|8.0) TB/ {print $NF; exit}'
```

This will look for the first line that says `1.0 TB` or `5.0 TB` or `8.0 TB` on it, and print the last field, which happens to be the disk ID

To save that value in a variable, use command substitution:

```
disk_id="$(diskutil list | awk '/(1.0|5.0|8.0) TB/ {print $NF; exit}')"
```

now the variable `disk_id` will contain the output of the command

Comment: Hi Eric. I'm getting no output from that command unfortunately. Could that be because in the example you linked to they are actually doing "diskutil cs list" rather than "diskutil list" which gives a different out. It would have to be with the standard "diskutil list" to show all the drives and not just CoreStorage volumes.

Comment: @DannyShepherd then you'll have to give me an example of the output.  I don't have access to `diskutil` so unless you edit your question to include the text you want to process I'll just be left guessing at what to parse

Comment: Hi @Eric have added an example of the print out from diskutil list

Comment: @DannyShepherd thanks, I updated my answer to show how to get the disk ID for the first instance of a particular size

Comment: Hi Eric, that's perfect! How can I take that answer and use it in a variable in a follow up command? Eg, now I know it's "disk0" for instance, how can I do diskutil info $result

Comment: In bash you can use `$(...)` around any command to get the `stdout` of the command back as a string, just assign that to a variable and you've got it. . . I'll update to show